# docbook multi-column layout

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, docbook

trying to figure out how to control the text flow in a columned layout. I am using the `lang="he"` property, and have `writing-mode` set to rtl:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="root.properties">
 <xsl:attribute name="writing-mode">rl-tb</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

still when I set `<xsl:param name="column.count.body">2</xsl:param>` text flows from the left column to the right one. How can I fix this? TIA.

`update:`
with Kevin's help got XEP to process my .fo file and the text flow in columns was fine. So looks like an FOP bug.

Comment: Please specify what product you are using to produce the document from XSL FO.

Comment: FOP, should it matter?

Comment: Yes it should, not every formatting engine supports all the rules behind rl-tb formatting. Why not try with a different engine and then report whether there is an issue.

Comment: hmm, I'm not familiar with many XSL-FO engines. I tried XEP and it looks like it will take a lot of config to get it working, any suggestions for an engine that can be tried without too much effort?

Comment: Just a note to this, it takes only a few minutes to get RenderX running and offline I did that with the OP today for good results showing the issue is not with their FO but rather the processor used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to finalize this question with an answer, some FO Processors do not respect left to right formatting in terms of column (or page) layout. The OP was using FOP and tested with RenderX XEP and found that XEP does support two column layout in right to left languages as shoudl be done (column layout is also right to left).